# Why background-color property is not assignable

Tags: javascript

I have a div with the id #one. I set the background color to be red. I want the option to change this to a random color when the div is clicked on, so I made a function to do this. My question:

Why does it not work when I write 'background-color' instead of 'backgroundColor' in JS? If I write 'background-color', then I get an error saying that there's a bad assignment on the left of the operator. Thanks in advance!

Code:

https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/pLebyj

```
//This works:

var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

function change() {
  document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor=col;
}

//This doesn't:

var col = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

function change() {
  document.getElementById("one").style.background-color=col;
}
```

Comment: You can use `background-color` only in CSS but in JavaScript, you can use camel case. For example if it is `font-family` you can write down as `fontFamily`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I guess I only used the kebab case because that was the property I was trying to access in CSS via JS. I will remember to convert the dashed properties to camel case next time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Because `-` is an operator in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim Do you know if there is a way to keep changing the color of the square when you continue to click on it? With the onclick, the color only changes once, then you have to reload the page to change it again. I'm still learning JS by the way.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim upvoted, and many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify a CSS property in JavaScript that contains a dash, simply remove the dash. For example, `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`, the `border-radius` property transforms into `borderRadius`, and so on.

You can't use `-` in JavaScript because `-` is a special keyword. For example, if you are using:

```
background-color
```

It means you are subtracting two variables `background` and `color`.

Your code changes background color only once, if you want to change color on everytime then you need this:

```
let r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
let r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
let r3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
element.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r1},${r2},${r3})`;
```

Comment: Awesome - will remember this in future.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this situation, since the difference between full bright and one less than full bright isn't really perceivable to the human eye, but because [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive), `Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)` will only produce numbers between `0` and `254`. To get the full range up to `255`, multiply by `256`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript attributes and variables are using camel case syntax. Moreover, dashes are forbidden in this case because they would be interpreted as a substract operator. That's why you get this error.